# iOS: Streaming of large file

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin.ios, filestream

I want to stream a large data file for a game continuously from the disk of a iOS device.
The question is if anyone has streamed such files ( Blocks of 20MB ) before by using a `System.IO.FileStream`. I have no iOS-device do test it myself and i not expect to get one in the next time.

There are 2 questions:

- Is the file streamed without loading it fully ( The behaviour which i expect from a stream but i'm unsure about the handling of MonoTouch ) and how is the memory usage while streaming it?
- How is the performance of the loading process, especially when loading different files at once?

Thank you for any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoTouch base class libraries (BCL) comes from Mono so a lot of the code is available as open source. In the case of [`FileStream`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2-10/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs#L1138) you can see the code on github.

> Is the file streamed without loading it fully ( The behaviour which i expect from a stream but i'm unsure about the handling of MonoTouch )

You're right, it won't be fully loaded. You'll control what's being read.

> and how is the memory usage while streaming it?

The above link shows that the default buffer size is set to **8192** bytes (8k) but that several constructors allows you to use a different size (if you wish so).

> and how is the memory usage while streaming it?

But that buffer is an internal buffer. You'll provide your own buffer when you call methods like [`Read`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2-10/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs#L509) so you will be, again, in control of how much memory is being used.

> How is the performance of the loading process, especially when loading different files at once?

That's difficult to predict and will largely depend on your application (e.g. number of files, total memory required...). You can use `FileStream` asynchronous methods, like [`BeginRead`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2-10/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs#L579), to get better performance if required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems that iOS has a acceptable I/O performance. ( http://forums.imore.com/iphone-4s-forum/221365-iphone-4s-i-o-performance.html )

Comment: The default buffer size is really an implementation detail (and will actually change to 4096 some day in MonoTouch - this change has already happened in mono master).